# ID3082: The request scope is not valid or is unsupported

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have deployed CRM 2011 in IFD mode.

While creating user through CRM web service I got this error:

```
ID3082: The request scope is not valid or is unsupported
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the account used is a domain account?

Comment: I missed to say something earlier. User creation was happening after few hours may be 4 or 5. But now I got a root cause of the problem. If I update the "Relying parties identifiers" after Oranization creation, the user creation happening successfully immediately. Though I don't have a solution of this problem. any idea from anyone ?